# ios app kept open for long time becomes unresponsive

Tags: ios, xcode, timer

I have a ios application which have timers running and shown on the uilabels. This app will ideally run for long durations eg: 12 - 14 hours but there will be user interactions in between frequently.
For testing i started the application and the timer on screen started, i left it for 7 hours without touching it (i have configured the screen not to get off) and the app was in the foreground running. But after 7 hours when i clicked on another button or did any other activity the application behaved in a weird way and on some occasions it became unresponsive.

I wanted to know if there is a time ( say 3 - 4 hours the app sitting ideal in foreground ) after which the app may/will behave in an unresponsive manner.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a memory leak? You can use Instruments to check

Comment: but i have used the application for straight 10 hours but with frequent user interactions every 30 mins or so. This problem only arises when i touch the iPad after very long duration... in this case 7 hours.